# Confustion with realpath() buffer

Tags: c, linked-list, memset, realpath

Here's my function, which is looking for regular files in given directory, and then storing full path to them in a list.

```
static my_func(const char *path, Files **list) //list - storage for file names
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];

    d = opendir(path);
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if ((DT_REG == dir->d_type)) {

                realpath(dir->d_name, buf);
                List_push(list, buf);
                printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
                // memset(buf, 0, PATH_MAX + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir(d);
    return 0;
}
...
...

int main()
{
    // list creation
    // my_func call
    ...
    List_print(...)
}
```

Expected output:

```
FILE_1.txt
FILE_2.txt
FILE_3.txt
FILE_4.txt
FILE_5.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_1.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_2.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_3.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_4.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_5.txt
```

The current output:

```
FILE_1.txt
FILE_2.txt
FILE_3.txt
FILE_4.txt
FILE_5.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_1.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_1.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_1.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_1.txt
/home/user/c/FILE_1.txt
```

Can it be related with my linked list implementation? It works fine, because I tested it with:

```
List_push(list, dir->d_name)
```

and got expected results. This is implementation of List_push (Files is just simply struct with `char *` and pointer to the next element):

```
void List_push(Files **head, char *x)
{
    Files *new;

    new   = malloc(sizeof(Files));

    if (NULL != new) {
        new->next = *head;
        new->text = x;
        *head = new;
    } else {
        printf("malloc error");
    }

}
```

Also, as you can see, I was trying to clear `buf` with memset, but without success - the output is:

```
FILE_1.txt
FILE_2.txt
FILE_3.txt
FILE_4.txt
FILE_5.txt






[console]$
```

Yes, blank space seems to be filed with something (or these are just `'\n'` symbols from List_print), so list is not empty.

What is wrong here?

Comment: You have to make a copy of the string so you don't keep a pointer to the changing buf[] variable.  Consider strdup().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `List_push(list, buf);` you store a pointer to `buf` in the list. You do this for each file, so you end up with several pointers to the same `buf` in the list. When printing the list items it then will show the (current) contents of `buf`.

To avoid this you need to create a copy of `buf` and store that, so that the stored data won't be overwritten when you reuse `buf` for the next file.